# Open the Phone (Call) with a button and a Text field/View (iPhone) and come back to the application back

Tags: iphone

Hello, I have successfully developed an application in which clicking on UIButton the Mobile no in UITextField dialled.

But I am not able to come back in my application. Is it possible to come back on the page from which I have dialled the Mobile number.

```
-(void)newuser:(id)sender;
{
    NSString *URLString = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:@")172-123456"];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, an application receiving a URL to process doesn't get information about the sender. Besides, as far as I know the Phone application doesn't have a Back button either.

Comment: ok....tom but i have succesfully come back on my application by calling facebook checkin near by places and come back on the same last page....But by dialling mobile no..i have to restart my application again...is this OK or a wrong method..

Comment: Depends on what you show. If Facebook has an SDK that allows you to go back where you came from, it'll work. As far as I know there's no API for the Phone, only the tel:// URLs - which don't allow the back button strategy.

Comment: When you dial some number from your application then your application will go in background and in ideal state.
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://123123"]];

Comment: means application is in ideal state...so it should come back automatic whenevr call ended....

Comment: That's assuming that the user actually clicks a URL in your application - you are doing it programmatically. I'd assume that the actual calling APIs are private.

Answer (score 1):

not sure which iOS version this was implemented in but I use this simple approach in my latest app '[App Time](http://itunes.apple.com/app/id482494990?mt=8)' which is to launch the call from within a UIWebview, but doesn't require anything more than...

```
     UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
     NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@tel://yourNumber"];
     [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:telURL]];
```

the user is prompted to confirm the call with a UIAlertview but will be brought back to the same screen after the call completes.